# Weird round icon in android studio instead of panel?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a weird round instead of a panel in Android Studio so nothing works. It works only after rebooting the laptop. Restarting studio not working. How to fix it?
[image]

Comment: does it show any information on hover over it? is it clickable?

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this? Did you try temporarily disabling all additional plugins you've installed if any?

Comment: @AgentP yes file / edit etc are clickable...

Comment: @VenomVendor its 4.0

Comment: Did you try temporarily disabling all additional plugins you've installed if any?

Comment: @VenomVendor no it sometimes appear by itself. And I must reboot laptop